# Black Screen After CPU Replacement

Tags: cpu

I have recently replaced my CPU, 
when i first booted the system up it started up normal and went to the desktop. 
After i checked some things the screens ( 2 ) went black and lost signal out of nowere, 
i does this all the time now and i think it has something to do with the cooling but i'm not sure so before i go trying stuff i want to know if i missed something.

I know the cpu is compatible with my motherboard and i checked all the cables.

Comment: Do you mean your screen is now always black even right after powering computer on or operating system boots and after some time screen goes black?

Comment: when it is not black, what readings are you getting on the CPU temp? you can use speedfan on windows, and lm-sensors on linux. what is the make and model of your new cpu?

Answer (score 0):

Laptop, right? The ribbon cable which provides signal and power to the screen can work loose just enough to fail, while looking like it's still connected. Suggested you unlock the cable, remove, reseat amd relock it.

If a desktop (and specifying the make and model in the question by editing it is a very good idea) then shutdown, remove and reseat the video adapter card before powering back up. Please also check the cables at the back of the monitor in this case; I know you checked them at the PC, but the cables can work loose on the monitor side, too.